# saving word by word ,from each line , from a file in c

Tags: c, file

Suppose we have some contacts in a file, like a small phone book.

I want to make a small programme that works like an online phone book each contact in the text takes the size of a `Line` and, the order that the Information is placed looks like this : `NAME SURNAME ADRESS PHONE`,
but the Number of phones that each contact has can be more then one.
so for example :

```
 George Mikels "green str" 123123 12121232 
 Maria Luis "olive str" 6548845
```

In my attempt I have done this so far:

```
void Createtree(node **head_node)
{
    int count=0,*phones;
    char filename[50], name[30], surname[50], adress[70];
    char c;

    FILE *fp;
    printf("PLease enter the name of the file\n");
    scanf("%s", &filename);

    fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to open file");
        return ;
    }

    do
    {
        c=fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s ", &name, &surname, &adress);

        //takes the name ,surname and adress
        printf(" %s %s %s\n", &name, &surname, &adress);
        phones = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

        //creates a dynamic array of int in order to save the phones
        do
        {
            //saves each Number inside the array
            c = fscanf(fp, " %d ", phones[count]);
            count = count + 1;

            phones = (int*)realloc(phones, (count +1) * sizeof(int));

            // increases the size of the array in order to save all the phones 
        }while(c != '\n');

        //does it until the end of the Line 
        count=0;

        Insert(head_node,name,surname,phones);
        //uses a function to add the Information to a list 

    }while(c != EOF);
};
```

I can't save the phones inside the array and I don't know why.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing currently.

Comment: i cant save the phones inside the array and i dont know why

Comment: `%s` of `scanf` does not include white-spaces. so `%d` does not allow the rest of the address.

Comment: you mean that the should have or shouldent ?

Comment: you must read from `"` to `"` for `adress`.

Comment: I guess in your country no phone number start with 0, otherwise you should use strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try allocating the array before the reading and then the actual reading would initialize array's elements.

```
// define max number size
int maxSizeOfNumber = 20;

// allocate dynamic memory
int *phones = malloc(maxSizeOfNumber * sizeof(int));

// read phone number
do {

    c = fscanf(fp, "%d", &phones[count]);
    count++;

} while (c > 0 && count < maxSizeOfNumber );
```

---

I would advice you to store phone numbers either in character array or string to avoid numbers that would not be stored in an `int`, for example those starting with `0`'s, as mentioned in the comment section by @Bob__.

Comment: that fixed a part but now it seems it cant get out of the inside do-while .

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `c = fscanf(fp, "%d", &phones[i]);` or  `c = fscanf(fp, "%d", phones+i);`?

Comment: @cv13 Glad that I could help!

Comment: @cv13 If there isn't anything else that you want to be answered please click accept and close this post. Thank you!

Comment: `c` never become `'\n'`.

Comment: "`fscanf` returns the number of successfully matched and assigned input items or  `EOF` if it fails before matching any of the arguments."

Comment: @Bob__ I don't if it be better to make it `EOF` or remove it from the `while` condition. What do you think would be better

Comment: Maybe is better to use `fgets()` to get each line in and then `sscanf()` that to extract values.

Comment: yup it turns it didnt